# Can we download a classic report with all the formatting using Apex office print?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Is there any way to download a complete classic report in excel with all the formatting i.e exactly in the same way how it is visible on apex screen ?
If yes, can you please suggest how can that be done?

I have downloaded the interactive reports using APEX office print using tag : '{&interactive_1}'. But not sure how to download a classic report.

Regards,
Abha

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Lf5Tw80bt8 can you try this?

Comment: This video Shows about the Interactive report. But I want to download a classic report with formatting..Do you have such an example for classic report ?

Comment: You can use {&static_id&} for Classic Reports and Interactive Grids.